# Can put a link in a video element

Tags: javascript

So I'm trying to put a link inside a Video element and It wont work here is the code, also How do You make a Variable as string in JS ??

```
    var link = prompt("Enter The Website You Wanna Stream:");
    document.getElementById("PLAYER").innerHTML = "<source src='" + link + "' type='video'>";
```

Comment: So I found the answer a few minutes after I posted this which is that I have to put the Java Script Code after the element or I have to wait For the whole page to load then execute the code. If you have another way to solve this feel free to post

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple way of changing the source of a video based on your code in js:

```js
const link = prompt('Enter video Link');
const video = document.querySelector('video');
video.src = link;
```

full code for a test:

```js
setTimeout(() =>{

// setting a timeout of 3s

const link = prompt('Enter video Link');
const video = document.querySelector('video');
video.src = link;

} , 3000)
```

```html
<video src="https://hw5.cdn.asset.aparat.com/aparat-video/09b40b525d19c2459557117619da2c7f12978678-240p.mp4?wmsAuthSign=eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJ0b2tlbiI6IjlkNTQwYTJiMmNkZDAzMDFjODNlNjIxNjlmOWVjY2ZkIiwiZXhwIjoxNjM5MDkyNTY4LCJpc3MiOiJTYWJhIElkZWEgR1NJRyJ9.PTLqt9ltqbosdJr27icnfc_4PhUG4oVX2_IPxVXdqro" autoplay muted controls></video>
```

and to make a variable string you can use `.toString()`

```js
const num = 123;
const str = num.toString();
```

bear in mind in too many cases `.toString()` is not needed in js. I suggest you see: [js data types](https://www.programiz.com/javascript/data-types) as well as js [operators](https://www.programiz.com/javascript/operators)

Answer (score 1):

Your code is ok. You need only wrapped in the video Tag.

```js
function myFunction() {
  const link = prompt("Enter The Website You Wanna Stream:");
  if (link != null) {
    document.getElementById("PLAYER").innerHTML = `<video width="320" height="240" controls>
  <source src="movie.mp4" type="video/mp4">  
Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>`;
  }
}
```

```html
<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<div id="PLAYER"></div>
```